# Is it possible that after kernel panic the system will stay alive?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, panic

Yesterday, while running my application, I saw in the console `syslog` broadcast, which looks like kernel panic and the console became not responsive. Today, I noticed that I can connect to the server with `putty` and when I run `uptime` shows the system is up for few days. When I run `dmesg` I see `oom_killer` log and `Oops` log but I expected that I will see the system rebooted and the `dmesg` is clean of any traces of the kernel panic. So now I'm confused, was there a kernel panic? If yes, then how come I can connect to the server while it seems like the system wasn't rebooted (it's up for few days). If no, then how come I can connect to the server at all? shouldn't the server be frozen until I manually reboot it?

Comment: Panic != Oops (Panic = can't continue, oops = some bug, which may be fatal and trigger a panic (e.g: oops in interrupt context), or not)

Comment: BTW, I'm sure this has been asked before in unix.SE

Comment: Why don't you elaborate more and and address the oom_killer log, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/whats-the-difference-between-a-kernel-oops-and-a-kernel-panic

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. As mentioned in the comments to the question Oops is not kernel panic, the oom killer killed the process which run out of memory, since this process circumvents the kernel network stack (implements it in its own way) I got the oom log. What confused me is if I'll make a test program with

```
int * p = new int[(unsigned int)-1];
```

I will get `std::bad_alloc` and nothing about oom killer. More info you can find here:

http://bl0rg.krunch.be/oom-frag.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/what-is-a-kernel-panic